Study the variation of a function according to changes of a constrained variable
I am working on the maths behind constant product market makers (CPMMs).
The main underlying equation is $R_XR_Y = K$ where $R_X$ and $R_Y$ are the reserves of two assets, and $K$ is a constant. When trading with a CPMM, you trade against its reserves, so for instance if I wanted to buy asset $Y$ (selling $X$), I would inject in its reserves $X (R_X \uparrow)$ and I would receive $Y$ ($R_Y \downarrow$).
We can derive the amount of asset $Y$, $\delta_Y$ I receive from the aforementioned swap by selling $\delta_X$ through
$$(R_X+\delta_X)(R_Y-\delta_Y) = R_XR_Y \implies \delta_Y = \frac{R_Y\delta_X}{R_X+\delta_X}$$
Then, we can define the price of $Y$ relative to $X$ as the amount of asset $Y$ I receive in exchange for $X$, hence $$P_{Y/X} = \frac{\delta_X}{\delta_Y} = \frac{R_X+\delta_X}{R_Y}$$
We can see how the price changes according to the size of the trade: the larger the amount $\delta_X$ exchanged, the higher the relative price $P_{Y/X}$, and hence the less advantageous the trade.
We notice how $$P_{Y/X} = \frac{R_X}{R_Y} \text{ as } \delta_X \rightarrow 0$$
We defined the instantaneous price $P^*_{Y/X}$ as the price that would be achieved by an infinitesimally small trade.
We also define the price impact $\phi$ as the percentage difference between the instantaneous price and the actual relative price paid to buy the token, taking into account the size of the trade. Hence:
$$\phi = \frac{P^*_{Y/X} - P_{Y/X}}{P_{Y/X}} = - \frac{\delta_X}{R_X+\delta_X}$$
Empirically, we have that $-1 < \phi < 0$, where the closer it is to $0$, the lower the price impact.
Now, if we take the partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $R_X$  we have that$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial R_X} = \frac{\delta_X}{(R_X+ \delta_X)^2}$$ This stands to show that as the reserves skews towards asset $X$ (since $K$ is constant) $\phi$ increases and hence the price impact goes down.
We can use the same approach for $R_Y$, since $R_X = \frac{K}{R_Y}$
$$\phi = - \frac{\delta_XR_Y}{K + \delta_XR_Y}$$
We can partially differentiate as $K$ is constant:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial R_Y} = - \frac{K \delta_X}{(\delta_XR_Y + K)^2}$$
We indeed achieve the expected result, where as the reserves skew towards asset $Y$ ($R_Y \uparrow$), $\phi$ becomes lower, and hence the price impact increases. This is in line with our expectations because of the constraint $R_XR_Y = K$, where if $R_Y$ increases, $R_X$ decreases.
Here is where I need help
Now I would like to study the effects of $K \uparrow$ on $\phi$. This can occur when assets are added to both reserves as to increase the liquidity of the CPMM. Obviously I can't differentiate $\phi$ partially with respect to $K$, since it would imply keeping $R_Y$ constant which isn't the case (as $K$ increases, both $R_X$ and $R_Y$ increase).
Now, how can $K$ increase? When $K$ increase, $R_X$ and $R_Y$ increase maintaining the ratio defined by the current pool reserves.
Hence, an increase in $K$ by a factor of $\beta$, the reserves $R_X$ and $R_Y$ need to increase by a factor of $\sqrt{\beta}$.
Now, this is how $R_X$ and $R_Y$ vary according to a change in $K$, but I am significantly struggling to apply this to study the change of $\phi$ with changes in $K$.

Your claim that $R_X$ and $R_Y$ both increase as $K$ increases is certainly false from a mathematical perspective. Your original formula for $\phi$ seems to indicate that $\phi$ doesn’t depend on $K$ at all.

@TedShifrin Thanks for your feedback. Could you please elaborate? Why is it false that $R_X$ and $R_Y$ both increase as $K$ increases? And how can $\phi$ not depend on $K$ if it depends on $R_X$ which in turn depends on $K$?

It is pretty clear that if $K$ doubles and $R_X$ more than doubles that $R_Y$ must decrease. This being said: a change of $K$ looks to me more like a change of units, not really making an interesting change to the model.

@KurtG. This is where the constraint comes in. If $K$ doubles, $R_X$ can only increase by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ along with $R_Y$.
